# Changing the background color of certain cells in Excel using Applescript

Tags: excel, applescript

So I was wondering if you could change the background color of certain cells in Microsoft Excel using Applescript.

I've understood how one can target specific cells but neither `back color` (contained in the scripting dictionary), `background color` (not contained in the scripting dictionary) nor `color` result in anything but `missing value`'s and errors. This is my code so far:

```applescript
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set back color of cell "A1" of front sheet of front document to {255, 244, 233}
```

Comment: In VBA, the property is `RangeObject.Interior.Color` perhaps `color of interior of cell` or something like that might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranges/cells have an 'interior' which you can access using `interior object`. Look for 'interior' in the dictionary. There are other associated properties as well. You can also affect border colours similarly.

So…

```
set color of interior object of range "A1" to {255, 244, 233}
```

You can also apply some of the preset colours by applying a color index, like so…

```
set color index of interior object of range "A1" to 6
```

There is a method to getting the myriad color index numbers but I've forgotten what it is (other than trial and error). But if you assign a colour by clicking on a palette, you can then `get color index` for that range. Actually, the applescript doc for excel has a palette table with the numbers.